# Having issues while constructing a test vector text file for Logisim?

Tags: automated-tests

First of all I want to mention that I am using Logisim -Evolution Version - 3.4.1 for all my logical circuits simulation. The link to this Logisim software is :
https://github.com/reds-heig/logisim-evolution

Now the issue I am facing is I had an assignment to construct an ALU using this software by using this
YouTube video as a reference whose link is :
https://youtu.be/lvYCchzQTyE
at time stamp - 20:30
he opens up his test vector , which basically is used to dry run some cases on your circuit.

Now i tried to recreate this truth table in a text file whose link is :
https://paste.sh/3-ovBHtY#fE_SwK99-tv_VQmtlJCALNHA

But when i am trying to load this .txt file as my test vector i am faced with this error message :

[The error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2QgV.png)

It states that it's not able to parse multiple bit for a single column for eg .:
in columns A I have multi-bit values as '1011' e.t.c which it's unable to parse.

I wanted the exact same truth table that he got in his video at - 20:30
but there's that parsing error coming up and again.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve this issue is to take a screenshot of the table from the youtube video itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://weinman.cs.grinnell.edu/courses/CSC211/2018F/assignments/combinational-logic/
If you have 4 bit pin A write in text A[4]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).